# Have a tag for every single device?

Tags: discussion, tags

As seen in

[How do I replace the Li-ion battery in a Kenwood TM-741A?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/12887/how-do-i-replace-the-li-ion-battery-in-a-kenwood-tm-741a)

we've got device-specific tags.

Now, I'd like to think it'd be a good idea to have a guideline on whether to tag with the individual device type.

I'd go with "no", because that means an endless flood of tags which will mostly have one question tagged with it.

But: there's arguments for "yes": If you have experience with a *Skynet T-1000 multi-band transceiver with Band-Reshaping*, you might want to watch questions tagged [t-1000](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t-1000). That way, you'd get an email when someone tags their question. On the other hand, subscribing (as far as I know) only works for *existing* tags, so you'd need to *ask* a "dummy" question first if you're the first to want to have a device.

Comment: Here's some guidelines for the use and creation of tags:

Comment: https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Comment: https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/tagging

Comment: @MikeWaters yeah, but that all breaks down to *you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.* <-- and that's exactly the thing I'm trying to discuss here: is a device a *topic* or just a specificity.

Comment: There's already too many tags for me to remember. :-) Having said that, there will always be the need for new ones from time to time.

Comment: One way to search for new questions and answers on a subject is to periodically Google *t-1000 site:ham.stackexchange.com*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Early on, we followed the principle of having manufacturer tags but not device tags, essentially for the reason you state. But we haven't been deleting them when they're created, and I currently don't see a specific problem with it — if you look at [the relevant section of the list of tags](https://ham.stackexchange.com/tags?page=8&tab=popular) it's not particularly full of model tags with single uses.

> I'd go with "no", because that means an endless flood of tags which will mostly have one question tagged with it.

Actually, [the system will delete tags with only one use](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) — oh, apparently it's optional and we don't have that feature enabled. We could turn it on if this becomes an issue.

My current opinion on this issue is “wait and see, set a policy if it turns out we need one”. I'll be happy to deal with the retagging work if needed.

Comment: Agreed. But we're always open to your suggestions and comments, Marcus.

Comment: @MikeWaters never doubted that. But, thank you :)