# Please create tags for BNC connectors and N type connectors

Tags: support, tags

Ham-in-training and new members here. I've been frequently asking questions and getting great feedback here.

I asked [PL-259/SO-239 vs N Type vs BNC when to use which?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/13061/pl-259-so-239-vs-n-type-vs-bnc-when-to-use-which) and found that while the tag for `pl-259-so-239-connector` exists, the ones for `n-type-connector` and `bnc-connector` do not yet exist. I don't have the reputation to create those tags yet, could someone please create them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done. Tags have to be on at least one question, so I added them to your question.

Note that tags should generally be broad enough to have plenty of content (compare [Have a tag for every single device?](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361/have-a-tag-for-every-single-device)) and rarely-occurring things are better handled by just being able to search for the terms. I'm slightly unsure about this family of tags, but I can imagine people asking questions about the specific connectors (crimping, identification of impedance, etc), so I think it's above the threshold.