# Should tags be created for ITU regions?

Tags: discussion

[Kevin Reid AG6YO](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/a/367/14220) already explained to me that tags should be broad enough to include an entire category, however, I [Safeguards against cross-border abuse?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/safeguards-against-cross-border-abuse), which I suspect is specific for ITU Region 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You now have enough reputation to [create tags yourself](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (150).

That said, if you feel that your question is about region 3 in particular you should *also* mention that in the text of your question. As it is now, it reads as a general question merely prompted by your experience in region 3, and it's gotten a general answer.

Comment: I mention region 3 in the first sentence, "I live in a country that falls under ITU region three". Since I'm not aware of whether the IARU or IARU region 3 would handle such an issue, I posed the question as such.

Comment: @AminShahGilani Most of the time, people intend to ask general questions and your question still reads that way to me. I really do recommend rephrasing it to be clear that you're specifically interested in local procedures. (And creating the tag if you wish; [tag:itu-region-3] seems like a reasonable spelling.)

Comment: I see, thank you